# CSS class inheritance/ selectors

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

Probably a simple enough questions for you CSS buffs:

I have a simple unordered list:

```
<ul><li>Hello</li></ul>
```

I want to apply the following css class to it:

```
.style {
   height: 100%x;
   width: 100%;
}

.style ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.style li {
    //stuff
}
```

Assuming my list has no parent container (I am building a plugin so who knows how people will apply it) what is the most efficient way to apply these styles to these elements?  I thought if I applied the `.style` class to ul than the list would automatically inherit all the child classes.  This seems to not be the case.  Do I have to loop each element and apply the specific class?

Comment: If you don't know how people will be using your list, why do you want to specify 100% width and height on its parent?

Comment: @Artyom it was just an example.  But a fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `style` class to your `ul` and use the following CSS selectors:

```
ul.style {
   height: 100%x;
   width: 100%;
}

ul.style {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.style li {
    //stuff
}
```

---

`.style ul` is stating "style the any `ul` which is nested within an element which has a `style` class."

Answer (score 0):

Add `.style` class to your `ul` and the css should be like this:

```
ul.style { 
    list-style-type: none; 
} 

ul.style li { 
    //stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need at the very least an element to contain the style class.

```
<div class="style"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
```

Otherwise your style's are not going to be applied.